# Keyed Particles don't render

Tags: rendering, particles

I made a Keyed particle animation. I have 3 base objects with particle systems and a 4th object with Keyed set in the particle system settings. So the particles travel between 3 states/objects. The animation is ok. But none of the particles render. Only the base shape of the objects, such as the C2 text, but not the particles assigned to it. I have all particles set to render halos. I would like to render only the particles, not the objects' mesh. Please see attached image.

[image]

Comment: Uncheck emitter if you don't want to render the emitter object's mesh

Comment: Ok, done. But I still don't see particles in the render.

Comment: Might pay to create a sample file.  Could it be your RenderLayers, is halo checked?

Comment: Hm. I can't upload the file to Blend-Exchange, it's too big. Don't know how to make it lighter. But I did something smart. I used a little light emitting sphere to use as the particles, and it renders properly. So only the Halo doesn't render. I checked RenderLayer and there is no switch for Halo. So my problem is solved, but I still would like to know about the Halo and why it doesn't render.